# Remove Spaces from Advanced Custom Field if empty

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

Trying to remove the whitespace before the , if the $middle field is empty. This is the code I have

```
function show_update_postdata( $value, $post_id, $field ) {

// Get values from POST
$first = $_POST['acf']['field_5b8536ef3839f'];
$middle = $_POST['acf']['field_5b853701383a0'];
$last = $_POST['acf']['field_5b8536e53839e'];
$creds= $_POST['acf']['field_5b853717383a1'];

// Custom post title
$title = $last . ', ' . $first . ' '. $middle .', ' . $creds;
$slug = sanitize_title( $title );
$postdata = array(
  'ID'          => $post_id,
  'post_title'  => $title,
  'post_type'   => 'physicians',
  'post_name'   => $slug
);

wp_update_post( $postdata );
    return $value;
}

add_filter('acf/update_value/name=first_name', 'show_update_postdata', 10, 3);
add_filter('acf/update_value/name=middle_name_initial', 'show_update_postdata', 10, 3);
add_filter('acf/update_value/name=last_name', 'show_update_postdata', 10, 3);
add_filter('acf/update_value/name=credentials', 'show_update_postdata', 10, 3);
```

Currently the output is Doe, John D., MD if the $middle has a value, but if the $middle has no value I am getting this Doe, John , MD but it should be Doe, John, MD

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> but if the $middle has no value I am getting this Doe, John , MD

Just because $middle is empty, the space character inserted before it does not automatically disappear with it.

So check if the variable is empty, and only if not, insert the space and the value:

```
$title = $last . ', ' . $first . ( $middle != '' ? ' '.$middle : '' ) .', ' . $creds;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `trim()` function to...

> Strip whitespace (or other characters) from the beginning and end of a
>   string

```
if(empty($middle)) $middle = trim($middle);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use rtrim function instead of trim to validate every single variable and url.

```
$var=rtrim($variable);
$var=ltrim($var);
```

otherwise empty() check is the best solution

```
if(empty($variable))
```